# Hide or Remove the log-in link from the "welcome email" send by wordpress for new users

Tags: wordpress, email, authentication

I think the title says it all.

I need to hide or remove the login link that is sent by wordpress in the "welcome email" to the new user that has registered

Now the mail consist in
Username
Password
Link

I just need that link to go.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate new user email you can override the `wp_new_user_notification()` funcion placed in `/wp-includes/pluggable.php`. As you can only override pluggable functions in a plugin, not via `functions.php`, you should create a simple plugin with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom welcome email
 */

if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) :
    function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass = '') {
            $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

            $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

            $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your site %s:'), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user->user_email) . "\r\n";

            @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), $blogname), $message);

            if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
                    return;

            //$message  = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n";
            //$message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n";
            $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

            wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);

    }
endif;
```

Simpler solution might be using the following plugin: [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/welcome-email-editor/).

Comment: I am already using a plugin called WP Better Emails that allows me to style the welcome email a bit more, but doesnt have this option to remove the link.

Comment: Right! Any idea how to override the wp_new_user_notification() function?

Comment: You should create a custom plugin, check my newest edit.

Comment: I am not that skilled.. I ll try it out!